# SpringBoot Elastisearch RestHighLevelClient Java Search-API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, rest-client

I'm following this [Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/18148/spring-boot-elasticsearch) and everything works fine.
Except I wan to add some extra search functionalities.

I have the following document is my Elasticsearch 6.1 index:

```
{
    "author": "georges",
    "price": 99.1,
    "id": "06e68109-504a-44d6-bf2e-0debb12c984d",
    "title": "Java Always"
}
```

My Spring Boot app runs on port 8080. I know how to insert data by using following API with postman : `127.0.0.1:8080/books` and also how to get the book with its ID `127.0.0.1:8080/books/06e68109-504a-44d6-bf2e-0debb12c984d` thanks to the **GET request** provided by E-S [Java High Level Rest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.1/java-rest-high-document-get.html):

```
    //This works perfectly thank you

@Repository
public class BookDao {
 private final String INDEX = "bookdata";
 private final String TYPE = "books";
 private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    ...

 public Map<String, Object> getBookById(String id) {
 GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEX, TYPE, id);
 GetResponse getResponse = null;
 try {
      getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
       e.getLocalizedMessage();
       }
       Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = getResponse.getSourceAsMap();
                    return sourceAsMap;
       }
```

Question is: How can I search this book by it's **author** ?

I've tried exactly the same implementation but it doesnt work because GetRequest only gets documents by **Document id**

```
public Map<String, Object> getBookByAuthor(String author) throws IOException {

        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEX, TYPE, author);
        GetResponse getResponse = null;
        try {
            getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = getResponse.getSourceAsMap();

        return sourceAsMap;
    }
```

My controller:

```java
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.gvh.es.rest.es6rest.dao.BookDao;
import com.gvh.es.rest.es6rest.model.Book;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    private BookDao bookDao;

    public BookController(BookDao bookDao) {
        this.bookDao = bookDao;

    }



    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Map<String, Object> getBookById(@PathVariable String id){

      return bookDao.getBookById(id);
    }


    @PostMapping
    public Book insertBook(@RequestBody Book book) throws Exception {
      return bookDao.insertBook(book);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Map<String, Object> updateBookById(@RequestBody Book book, @PathVariable String id) {
      return bookDao.updateBookById(id, book);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteBookById(@PathVariable String id) {
      bookDao.deleteBookById(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the problem too,and this is my solution to the problem. It works with my code.
Change the *username* and *password*, and I think it may work.

```
private RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
    try {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });
        restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return restHighLevelClient;
}
```